# How to use for/while looping shapes in pygame to create a repeating pattern?

Tags: loops, pygame, offset

For a school assignment, we must create a picture using pygame shapes and I have an issue with a for loop using offset. I am trying to draw the dividing broken yellow lines on a road. However, the issue is that the lines repeat vertically. There are stacked on top of each other.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
white= [255,255,255]
red =   [255,  0,  0] 
size = [400,500]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while done == False:
   for event in pygame.event.get(): 
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
           done = True

   screen.fill(white)
   for y_offset in range(100,0,-10):
       pygame.draw.line(screen,red,[10,+y_offset],[100,0+y_offset],5)

   pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

If you use this code, it prints 10 red horizontal lines on top of each other. I would like to know how I can make the lines repeat horizontally instead of vertically. I have no idea how to make them like this: - - -
Can someone please help me with the looping process? I just don't understand the offsetting portion of it. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to repeat along x, so you need to use the offsets on your x values.

Comment: Just an FYI: [10,+y_offset],[100,0+y_offset], the + in the first brackets is useless, and the 0+ in the second one is also useless.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to give away the answer, but see if these 4 lines don't help you:

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, red, [10, 0], [100, 0], 5)
pygame.draw.line(screen, red, [110, 0], [200, 0], 5)
pygame.draw.line(screen, red, [210, 0], [300, 0], 5)
pygame.draw.line(screen, red, [310, 0], [400, 0], 5)
```

Also, I'm not even 100% sure that's what you want.

Comment: That is exactly what I want! However, my teacher wants us to use a loop with either while or for to make those lines. Instead of rewriting out the code again and again, she wants us to use a loop. I was just wondering if there was another way to write it Thanks

Comment: It's only meant to be a hint, I was leaving the loop logic to you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer! I used a while loop instead, but I found out that I had to add the +y_offset to the X COORDINATE instead of the Y. This allows it to repeat horizontally. Thank you for your help(:

```
y_offset = 0
while y_offset < 700:
    pygame.draw.line(screen,yellow,[0+y_offset,480],[50+y_offset,480],5)
    y_offset = y_offset+70
```